# Como executar uma ação ao atingir determinada altura do scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função em que toda vez que eu der *scroll* ele chama uma certa função, só que quero chamar ele apenas uma vez

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
        //aparece segundo menu
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= navHeight + section01Height){
            navSecundariaShow();
        }
        else if($(this).scrollTop() < navHeight + section01Height){
            navSecundariaHide();
        }

    });
```

Ou seja, assim que alcançar determinada altura do *scroll*, ele chama essa função.

Mas não pode chamar toda vez a partir dai, como faço?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A forma mais simples de resolver isso (se você quer que o evento seja ativado apenas **uma vez** cada vez que o usuário visitar a página.) seria usar uma variável pra checar se o comportamento já ocorreu (ou não).

```
var hasBeenTriggered = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    //aparece segundo menu
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= navHeight + section01Height && !hasBeenTriggered){
        navSecundariaShow();
        hasBeenTriggered = true;
    }
    else if($(this).scrollTop() < navHeight + section01Height && hasBeenTriggered){
        navSecundariaHide();
    }

});
```

Você também pode trocar o `&&` do `else if` por um condicional OR `||`, conforme a sua necessidade. Dessa forma a princípio ele verifica se o seu painel já foi exibido, se não foi, exibe e muda o estado para `true`. Assim, esse código não se executa mais, a não ser que você mude isso no código mais tarde.

Adicionalmente, você pode deixar o `&& hasBeenTriggered` do bloco `else if` que retornará sempre `true`se o painel já tiver sido aberto, para se certificar que o método `navSecundariaHide()`não seja chamado desnecessáriamente no futuro.

Não sei se era exatamente esse seu objetivo. Essa é a forma mais simples que consigo pensar no momento.

**EDIT:** Aplicando o exemplo do @Renato Tavares ao exemplo do OP, ficaria algo assim:

```
$(window).one('scroll', function(e){ ... }
```

Ao invés de chamar o método `.on(event,handler)`, trocá-lo por `.one(event,handler)` como sugerido faria com que o evento fosse ativado apenas a primeira vez que é chamado. Para outros usos pode-se ver o link que nosso colega colocou dos docs de jQuery. Embora não tenha tido tempo de testá-lo, parece que o uso seria até mais simples do que o uso da variável `hasBeenTriggered` conforme sugeri.

O *upside* de usar a variável seria o caso de você desejar verificar se o painel **ainda** está aberto ou fechado, dependendo de como é o fluxo do seu código e seu objetivo.

Comment: sensacional, não tenho nem como agradecer cara.

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou usar o `.one()` de [acordo com a documentação](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ele só é executado uma única vez. O exemplo é o seguinte:

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

No seu caso um `.off(event)` já deveria resolver:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  $( this ).off( event );
});
```

Comment: obrigado, funcionou também

Comment: A vantagem aqui é que você reduz o uso de variáveis globais.